# hiding and showing commandButton in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF(PrimeFaces).

I have two ***commandButtons*** Do and Undo. I want only one button to be visible at one time.

like, When I click Do button, onclicking Do button should hide(performing its action simultaneously) and Undo button should be visible 
and when i click Undo button onclicking it should hide and Do button should come back to active

I tried using
enable() and disable() methods but were of no use.
 Can I get some help in achieving this. any predefined methods available?

Heard *rendered* attribute will help but couldnt understand what exactly will the attribute do .
Can someone explain pls

Comment: The `rendered` attribute specifies if a component is rendered or not, not to be confused with the `disabled` attribute which makes a component rendered but not usable (clickable in your case). Could you provide your code for the two buttons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSF `rendered` attribute will define if the component should be rendered/visible or not.
If

```
<h:commandButton value="Undo" rendered="#{false}" />
```

Then your above `Undo` button will be hidden.

`rendered` attribute can be bound to a `ManagedBean` property. In case if you want this dynamic, you have to update the component to see the result.

Here is a Small Example:
XHTML:

```
<h:panelGroup id="doBtnPG">
    <h:commandButton value="Do" rendered="#{myBean.showDo}" action="#{myBean.doAction}">
       <f:ajax render="unDoBtnPG"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="unDoBtnPG">
     <h:commandButton value="Un Do" rendered="#{myBean.showUndo}" action="#{myBean.undoAction}">
        <f:ajax render="doBtnPG"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{
    private boolean showDo=true;
    private boolean showUndo=true;

    public void doAction(){
      showUndo=false;
    }

    public void undoAction(){
      showDo=false;
    }
    //SETTER and GETTERS
}
```

In the above example, on clicking on one button the corresponding action method makes the property on which other button is being rendered as `false`, `f:ajax` will re render/update the other button's `panelGroup` to reflect the changes.

Since you marked this question as `Primefaces`, here is the XHTML code for Primefaces:

```
<h:panelGroup id="doBtnPG">

    <p:commandButton value="Do" rendered="#{myBean.showDo}" 
            action="#{myBean.doAction}" update="unDoBtnPG"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="unDoBtnPG">

    <p:commandButton value="Un Do"  rendered="#{myBean.showUndo}" 
            action="#{myBean.undoAction}" update="doBtnPG"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Notice that on Primefaces `commandButtons` you dont need to use `f:ajax` or `p:ajax` explicitly because they are Ajax by default.

Please note that the functions `enable()` and `disable()` provided by Primefaces are only client side. When `disabled` attribute is `false` and if you enable the button using `enable()`, it will not fire your action method.